# QT Rectangle Wrap Around

Tags: qt, multiscreen

I'm working on a fullscreen project and I'd have two questions :

1) Is it possible to display my window in fullscreen on a multi screen setup ?

2) I need to make a rectangle wrap around my window, I mean that if it goes beyond the right edge, the exceeding part would be displayed on the left edge of my window, do you know how I could do that ?

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested, and displaying the window full screen displays it on the monitor it covers the largest area of.

About the rectangle wrap around, if it is outside the window, its edge will show up on the other monitor for sure. But it is strange to make an rectangle wrap around a fullscreen window...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :
1) that's the problem, I'd like to have the fullscreen on both of my screens not one
2) I don't see why it's so strange, I need to say that what goes out of my window by the right side comes back by the left side, as if my screen 1 was also my screen 3

Comment: Okay thanks El famoso I'll try to do it, I'm quite surprised that Qt doesn't have more options for multi screen setups